# Returning a print statement still shows the value

Tags: python

I tested the following code:

```
In [266]: def foo(): 
     ...:     print("yes") 
     ...:                                                                                                         

In [267]: def bar(): 
     ...:     return foo() 
     ...:                                                                                                         

In [268]: bar()                                                                                                   
yes

In [269]: x = bar()                                                                                               
yes
```

I am very puzzled about the result, it act as

```
In [274]: def foo(): 
     ...:     return print("yes %.1f" %12.333) 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                                         

In [275]: foo()                                                                                                   
yes 12.3
```

How should I understand this? much like shell script shell's command substitution `echo $(ls)`

Comment: You called `bar()`, which calls `foo()`, which prints (not _returns_, but _prints_) "yes".  What is the confusion?

Comment: Seems like you didn't try `x = bar(); print(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method you can do some actions and not return anything but directly show the result such as printing or returning a result and let another part of the code to utilize it.

So, I would like to explain what your code is doing:

```
In [266]: def foo(): 
     ...:     print("yes") # you are printing 'yes'
     ...:                                                                                                         

In [267]: def bar(): 
     ...:     return foo()  #you are returning a foo method
     ...:                                                                                                         

In [268]: bar()    # you are not directly calling foo()                                                                                            
yes

In [269]: x = bar()  # you are not directly calling foo() and this is equivalent to x = print('yes')                                                                                             
yes
```

Just a simple example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('Yes')
...
>>> def boo():
...     return foo()
...
>>> boo()
Yes
>>> x = boo() 
Yes
>>> x = print('Yes')
Yes
>>> x = 'Yes' # it is not printed
>>>
```

So, basically, a shell is not echoing any variable unless it is used in `print()`
However, if your method returns a value it will be printed. Basically in shell return will also play the printing roll.

```
>>> def noo():
...     return 'Yes'
...
>>> noo()
'Yes'
>>>
```

Comment: "However, if your method returns a value it will be printed" - only in the REPL

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and explanation, I think you are mistaken with shell script

In shell to return a string (for example) you can do like that

```
#!/bin/sh
foo()
{
  echo "my_string"
}

A=$(foo)
echo $A
```

value of $A will be "my_string"

To do the same in python

```
def foo():
    return "my_string"

a = foo()
print(a)
```

The reason we use the echo trick in shell scripts is due to the fact that `return` in shell can only return values between 0-255 which is not always what we want to do (as in your example or mine we want to return a string)

Please let me know if my answer is not clear enough I will improve it thanks to comments.